# Assigning different element IDs it elements of the same class

Tags: jquery

Been at this all morning, and I just cant get it to do what I want.

I have been using jQuery, which I am just learning.

My page has 6 sections, a few have id's and some don't.  They all share the same class.

My goal is to find each section and set the ID to a specific value. "A" "B" and so on.... I don't know how to accomplish this, so my plan was to create a loop and set the id's to "section1" "section2"..... then go back and change them to text values.

Not ideal, and it didn't work anyway.  This is what I did, the result is all the section id's were set to "section5".

I understand why it's doing what its doing.  The loop is finding the sections and setting ALL of the id's to "section0" then starting over.  I'm just not sure how to fix it.

Also, changing the id from "section5" to "F" isn't working either.

```
<script>
$(document).ready( function () {
    for(var i=0;i<6;i++){
        $('section.page-section').attr('id','section'+i+'');
    }
    $('#section0').attr('id', 'A');
    $('#section1').attr('id', 'B');
    $('#section2').attr('id', 'C');
    $('#section3').attr('id', 'D');
    $('#section4').attr('id', 'E');
    $('#section5').attr('id', 'F');
});
</script>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are selecting ALL the sections, every time and not the index you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are selecting ALL the elements on each loop and not the current one at the index you want to change.

```js
var sections = $('section.page-section')
for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
  sections.eq(i).attr('id', 'section' + i + '');
}
$('#section0').attr('id', 'A');
$('#section1').attr('id', 'B');
$('#section2').attr('id', 'C');
$('#section3').attr('id', 'D');
$('#section4').attr('id', 'E');
$('#section5').attr('id', 'F');
```

```css
.page-section::before {
  content: attr(id)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="page-section"></section>
<section class="page-section"></section>
<section class="page-section"></section>
<section class="page-section"></section>
<section class="page-section"></section>
<section class="page-section"></section>
```

How I would do it is using the attr method which gives you the index. What you return is what it will set. And made a function so you do not have to hardcode selectors to set the letter.

```js
function genChar(offset) {
  var start = "A".charCodeAt(0);
  return String.fromCharCode(start + offset);
}

var sections = $(".page-section").attr("id", function (index) {
  return genChar(index)
})
```

```css
.page-section::before {
  content: attr(id)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="page-section"></section>
<section class="page-section"></section>
<section class="page-section"></section>
<section class="page-section"></section>
<section class="page-section"></section>
<section class="page-section"></section>
<section class="page-section"></section>
<section class="page-section"></section>
<section class="page-section"></section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the implicit looping that the `prop` method will do, and use the index passed in to know what the id should be set as.

```js
$('section.page-section').prop('id', function(index){
  return 'section'+ index;
});

console.log(
  $('section.page-section').get()
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="page-section"></section>
<section class="page-section"></section>
<section class="page-section"></section>
<section class="page-section"></section>
<section class="page-section"></section>
<section class="page-section"></section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could rewrite your 1st attempt by using `:eq()` like so:

```js
for(var i=0;i<6;i++){
    $('section.page-section:eq(' + i + ')').attr('id','section'+i);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="page-section">1</section>
<section class="page-section">2</section>
<section class="page-section">3</section>
<section class="page-section">4</section>
<section class="page-section">5</section>
<section class="page-section">6</section>
```